# How could I connect to a second VPN when the first is capturing all the traffic?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

In my work, some times I need to connect to two VPNs at the same time (the company's one and the hosting provider's one).

THe problem is that the company's one is capturing all the traffic setting a route with a metric of 2.

The client is Cisco AnyConnect.

Is there a software workaround for this situation? I'm admin of my PC

Comment: Cisco AnyConnect is not just a VPN client, it is a security product. What you can and can’t do while connected to the VPN is dictated by company policy. One of those options being what traffic goes where.

Comment: If you tell us what you are trying to achieve by being connected to two VPNs, perhaps, we can explain how it can be accomplished.

Comment: @Ramhound I work with Drupal and there are many sites, I don't have credentials of all the sites (since they are different) and its easier to connect to Hosting company and create a drush uli (sign in url for admin). But since I have to use tokens for both VPN, its a waste of time disconnecting from one and connecting the other for a moment and then connect again to the main one.

Comment: Why does nobody ever edit their question when comments ask for clarification?